# azure table storage: entities filter query does not terminate

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am writing a filter query to find rows newer from a known datetime. This query I thought will run once and complete and return found records but rather this query does not complete. I could not find relevant documentation on the behaviour.

```
        TableQuery<Reading> partitionQuery = TableQuery.from(Reading.class);
        partitionQuery.setFilterString("PartitionKey eq 'partition1' and Timestamp gt datetime'2019-03-18T05:34:56+00:00'");
        partitionQuery.setTakeCount(100);


        Iterable<Reading> readingIterable = cloudTable.execute(partitionQuery);
        for (Reading entity : readingIterable) {
            System.out.println(entity.getPartitionKey() +
                    " " + entity.getRowKey() +
                    " " + entity.getTimestamp() 
            );
        }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by “query does not complete “?

Comment: say if i put a print statement following `for` statement, it would never be called. the iterable seems to be waiting for new rows.

Comment: Approximately how many entities are there in your table with PartitionKey = partition1?

Comment: Every one second a new record goes into each partition. Data is available almost for last one year. I am interested in only reading the newer data.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're seeing is correct. Basically what you're seeing is `Partition Scan`. A few things when it comes to table storage:

- Only `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` attributes are indexed.
- A query to table storage only returns a maximum of 1000 entities in a single request (it may not return any entities as well).
- Each query is assigned a maximum of 5 seconds to execute. If matching data is found, it is returned. If more data is available then a continuation token is returned and you must use that token along with the same query to get next set of data.

You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-timeout-and-pagination.

Now coming to your situation. You mentioned that you every second a new record is inserted in the same partition. Since you're querying on `PartitionKey` (indexed attribute) and `Timestamp` (non-indexed attribute), what the query is doing is starting from the top of the partition and trying to find matching entities. Because the latest entries are appended towards the end of the partition, the `execute` method is looping internally to find the matching entities and that could take a lot of time depending on how many entities you have in table.

To get the latest entries, I think you would need to rethink how you store the data. One solution would be to use the date/time when a record is created as PartitionKey. To prepend (instead of append), you could use `Reverse Ticks` mechanism (`(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks).ToString("d19")`). This was new entities are always added to the top of the table.

You may want to read this guide as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide.